# removing duplicates from a table which has association with another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
Student
_______________________
SudentId   Name
101        Peter
103        John
112        James
116        Peter
117        Peter


SudentId_Subject
_______________________
SudentId Subject
101      Physics
103      Chemistry
112      Mathematics
116      Physics
117      Commerce
```

To find duplicate students, I tried the query

`select * from Student group by Name having count(*)>1`, got

```
SudentId   Name
_______________________
101        Peter
116        Peter
117        Peter
```

Actually I need to filter students with the same subject. ie,

```
101        Peter
116        Peter
```

are duplicates (same subject) but not `117   Peter`

How can I write query for this?

Comment: Sometnihg like this? `select count(a.StudentId), a.Name from Student a, SudentId_Subject b  where b.EmpId = a.StudentId group by a.Name, b.Department`. Are you sure that there aren't two Peters that are working in the same Department?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have over complicated things, but couldn't think of an easier way :

```
SELECT ss.student_id,ss.name
FROM student ss
JOIN studentid_subject tt
 ON(ss.student_id = tt.student_id)
JOIN(SELECT t.name,s.department
     FROM student t
     JOIN studentid_subject s
      ON(t.student_id = s.student_id)
     GROUP BY t.name,s.department
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) p
 ON(ss.name = p.name and tt.department = p.department)
```

Comment: Thanks. let me try

Comment: it's "subject", not 'department' ;)

Comment: @JimishGamit Well, originally it was `department` when I wrote down the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

select * from student left join SudentId_Subject on Student.SudentId = SudentId_Subject.DepId where Student.SudentId=SudentId_Subject.DepId